Htaccess typo fixing "/\" before being turned into "//" by the browser
Im currently working SEO for a website and I'm having issues with typos in the URL's. For example product/\index.php would return a 404 despite being correctly redirected to the correct website.
I believe this is because /\ is illegal in URL's and thus, it's rewritten to product//index.php which is then redirected correctly but product/\index.php would still return a 404 code. Is there any way i could fix the product/\index.php without the browser transforming it to product//index.php?

If it really is the browser making this modification to the URL, before requesting it - then you won't be able to do anything about it on the server side afterwards.

Also I would suggest to fix the actual cause of the issue, not to try to somehow magically heal the symptom afterwards. The cause is the /\ here. Where does that come from? That needs to get fixed.

I do understand that most likely those URLs have somehow found it's way into the google catalog. Why ever. But fixing that appears secondary to me. Fix the actual cause, have the fixed URLs get crawled by the bot, then request removal of the faulty entries in the catalog.
